# Android getAssets() NullPointerException loading Json file from assets

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, android-context

I'm trying to get data from a json file so i can use it later with aChartEngine. this is the method i'm using to get this data:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;


        try {



            InputStream is = this.getAssets().open(ficheiro);

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

i'm using this method on other classes where i'm only displaying the json data in a listview (even without providing the context before getAssets()), however i can't get this to work this time.

LogCat:

```
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388): Process: com.example.euroxxi_testeficheiro, PID: 6388
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     ... 11 more
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:88)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.example.euroxxi_testeficheiro.ChartTeste.loadJSONFromAsset(ChartTeste.java:53)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.example.euroxxi_testeficheiro.ChartTeste.getIntent(ChartTeste.java:91)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.example.euroxxi_testeficheiro.MainActivity.ChartPlot(MainActivity.java:77)
05-20 10:26:14.108: E/AndroidRuntime(6388):     ... 14 more
```

this is the full activity

```
 package com.example.euroxxi_testeficheiro;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.BarGraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ChartTeste extends Activity{

    private static final String TAG_CENTRAL = "getCentrais_JSONResult";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "Central";
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "Data";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCAO = "Producao";
    String ficheiro = "getCentrais_JSON.json";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart_teste);

        getIntent();

    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;


        try {



            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("getCentrais_JSON.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }



    public Intent getIntent(Context context) 
    {   

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        try {

            String nome; 
            int producao; 


            // contacts JSONArray
            JSONArray centrais = null;

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());


            // Getting JSON Array node
            centrais = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CENTRAL);

            int[] y={0};
            String[] xLabel = {""};

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < centrais.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = centrais.getJSONObject(i);

                //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                nome = c.getString(TAG_NOME); 
                producao = c.getInt(TAG_PRODUCAO);


                xLabel[i]=nome;
                y[i]=producao;

                mRenderer.addXTextLabel(y[i], xLabel[i]);
            }  

             // Bar 1

                CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Grafico de producao");
                for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
                    series.add("Bar " + (j+1), y[j]);


                }


                dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());

                // This is how the "Graph" itself will look like
                mRenderer.setChartTitle("Gráfico de produção");
                mRenderer.setXTitle("X VALUES");
                mRenderer.setYTitle("Y VALUES");


                mRenderer.setXLabels(0);


                mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.GREEN);
                mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.RED);

                // Customize bar 1
                XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
                renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
                mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
              //renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(titleSize);  // if we change title text size, it will render off screen
                mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
                mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

        return intent;
    }

}
```

Comment: you call `getIntent()` and you have a method `getIntent(Context)` that takes context as a param.

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that `ChartTeste` is instantiated with `new`.  Never instantiate activities with `new`.

Comment: so should i change it to getIntent(this)? forgive me my ignorance i'm new to android

Comment: @laalto problem solved. i changed it to 

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChartTeste.class);

 startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: it's not showing my chart but at least the nullpointerexception is gone lol thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests that `ChartTeste` is instantiated with `new`. Never instantiate activities with `new`.

Either consider whether you need another activity at all, or use an `Intent` to instantiate one, e.g.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChartTeste.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Awesome..how did you find the op instantiated with new. context is null. Context is available once activity is created. with `new` context is null..

Comment: @Raghunandan The exception is from null basecontext i.e. the activity is not properly initialized and the most likely way to make it that far is to use `new` to instantiate an activity. Seeing one activity call another one directly in the stacktrace smells bad, too.

Comment: it's too bad i can't vote up yet lol thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("file_name.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

this may help you

Comment: Still the same thing, the variable "ficheiro" is the file name.

Comment: but you have to define file extension(like .txt,.json)

Comment: this is what i have now 

InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("getCentrais_JSON.json");

Comment: where's oncreate method of activity?

Comment: if you using this mehtod in other class then have to pass context of class in which you using this method

Answer (score 0):

```
this
```

refer to current object , in my opinion you should use

```
getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: i have tried this but it's still giving me the same error